# Debian device descriptor read 64 error 71

Tags: linux, debian, gnome

When I install debian on a computer without gnome, it gives me the above error when I connect usb device to my computer. But when I install gnome, the usb port works fine. How to get rid of this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That is the code for *Protocol error* (`EPROTO`). While there *have* been kernel issues that occasionally caused this, from my experience, this is usually a hardware issue with the USB subsystem.

The error message (which, incidentally, *you didn't post*) usually refers to the USB port that caused the issue. A few pieces of advice:

- Verify that the device is working properly on another computer.
- Check whether the device is working correctly on another USB port.
- Check your cables: 90% of such issues are caused by bad cables. Switching for another cable 
  could very well solve the issue.
- Check your connectors: This is a common issue on old computers where oxidization has settled on the USB port pins. You could try removing it by inserting and removing the USB plug repeatedly. *Warning: Don't overdo it - USB connectors can and will break if you do*.

I also doubt that GNOME has anything to do with the actual issue. It's far more probable that installing a windowing system merely hides the error message. It's probably still there in your `dmesg` output or the system logs.

It would help if you mentioned which USB device (make and model) causes this problem. Some devices are notorious for being rather unreliable...